# Clustering Markers Google Maps v2 onInfoWindow method

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I would like add method onInfoWindowClick based on example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

in class:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java

Method should work something like that:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Person person) {
    // Does nothing, but you could go into the user's profile page, for example.

    if (person.name.equals("JOHN"))
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=NEW+YORK")); startActivity(i);
```

Any suggestions what is wrong ?
        }

Comment: What you can do is register the variable Person inside a local variable and reuse it when you "onInfoWindowClick" since you have to tap a marker first to display the infoWindow.

Comment: Can show some simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have referenced with the CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity, you need to

1.) implement your own model renderer (PersonRenderer)

2.) in your PersonRenderer class, also implement the onClusterItemRendered method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(Person person, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(person, marker);
        markerCamLocMap.put(marker, person);
    }
```

3.) As you have already noticed, I also saved the "marker vs. person" pair into a HashMap, because marker is a class marked as final (as of today anyway), and we can't extend it to put more "stuff" into it (associate with data model) ....

4.) Later in your usual onInfoWindowClick method, which has the signature shown below

```
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
      Person person= markerCamLocMap.get(marker);
      if (person!= null && person.name.equals("JOHN") ) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=NEW+YORK")); startActivity(i);
      }
    }
```

You now can get hold of the "person" associated with the marker/infowindow, and do something accordingly.

You can probably tweak the HashMap to use the marker's ID as the key ( marker.getId() ), instead of using the marker itself as the key, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general solution on how to achieve this.

```
Marker profileMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("Profile Name").snippet("Snippet details"));

mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);                        
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_PROFILE_ID, profile_id);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```